# Exception in thread "main" java. lang. IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: indexoutofboundsexception

```
Reviewsq.size();
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++) {
    String rev = Reviewsq.get(i).text() + "\n";
    if (rev.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

I want to break and continue to other elements after the element is not found in Jsoup though am getting the above errors any idea how to rectify this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: Make sure your `Reviewsq` array contains atleast 2 elements

Comment: @user2073973 some have 0

Comment: @webscrapingtech Exactly...

Answer (score 0):

The obvious fix here would be to just use the size of the `Reviewsq` object in the bounds of the `for` loop:

```
for (int i=0; i < Reviewsq.size(); i++) {
    String rev = Reviewsq.get(i).text() + "\n";
    if (rev.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
}
```